# Sums of cubes of two complex matrices are closed under matrix multiplication

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, proof-writing

Show that the set of matrices $\{M^3+N^3:\ M,N\in M_n(\mathbb C)\}$ is closed under matrix multiplication.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What does it mean for an operation to be "intern"? That word is not in common use in mathematical English.

Comment: It means that for A,B,C,D,M,N in Mn(C), (A^3+B^3)(C^3+D^3) can be written as M^3+N^3.

Comment: In other words, the set is *closed* under multiplication. But maybe every complex matrix is a cube?

Comment: Ignore that – not every complex matrix is a cube.

Comment: Any help please?

Comment: The way you phrase the question, it seems you are convinced that the set is closed under multiplication. Why are you convinced of this?

Comment: It's an exercise given by my teacher, so it has to be true.

Comment: Has anyone made any significant progress?

Comment: Any thoughts on my answer, Morpheus?

Comment: I didn't give it a try, but it might work. I'm still looking for an elementary proof though.

Comment: What do you mean by "elementary"? Diagonalization is usually covered in introductory Linear Algebra courses.

Comment: Maybe you're right, i'll try to produce a proof following your hints. Thanks anyway

Comment: Although it doesn't seem too easy proving every matrix is a sum of two diagonalizable matrices, maybe you could help me out with that.

Comment: Hint: $$\pmatrix{5&1&0\cr0&5&1\cr0&0&5\cr}=\pmatrix{1&1&0\cr0&2&1\cr0&0&3\cr}+\pmatrix{4&0&0\cr0&3&0\cr0&0&2\cr}$$

Comment: Any progress, Morpheus?

Comment: Unfortunately i haven't made any significant progress, maybe because i know very few about diagonalization.

Comment: OK, I've written out a solution. When you get a solution from your teacher, if it's not the same as what I've written, please write it up and post it here, I'd like to see it.

Comment: Any comments on my solution, Morpheus?

Comment: Earth to Morpheus, come in, please.

Comment: Sorry, i couldn't answer you because I wasn't home. I'm still trying to understand your proof, but it seems correct. Thank you for taking the time to make this proof, and i'll definitely send you the teacher's correction when I get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you may be able to produce a proof by fleshing out the following sketch:

1. Every diagonalizable matrix is a cube of a matrix.
2. Every matrix is a sum of two diagonalizable matrices.
3. It follows that every matrix is a sum of two cubes.

Fleshing this out:

Let $A$ be a diagonalizable matrix. That means there's a diagonal matrix $D$, and an invertible matrix $P$, such that $A=P^{-1}DP$. There's a diagonal matrix $E$ such that $E^3=D$; just let each entry of $E$ be a cube root of the corresponding entry of $D$. Let $B=P^{-1}EP$. Then $$B^3=P^{-1}EPP^{-1}EPP^{-1}EP=P^{-1}E^3P=P^{-1}DP=A$$ Thus, every diagonalizable matrix is a cube.

Now every matrix $C$ is similar to a matrix in Jordan form, that is, there is a matrix $J$ in Jordan form and an invertible matrix $P$ such that $C=P^{-1}JP$. A matrix in Jordan form is composed of Jordan blocks $J_i$, $i=1,\dots,m$, $$J=\pmatrix{J_1&0&\dots&0\cr0&J_2&\dots&0\cr\vdots&{}&\ddots&\vdots\cr0&0&\dots&J_m\cr}$$ where each block $J_i$ is of the form $$J_i=\pmatrix{a_i&1&0&\dots&0\cr0&a_i&1&\dots&0\cr\vdots&{}&\ddots&\ddots&\vdots\cr\vdots&{}&{}&a_i&1\cr0&\dots&\dots&0&a_i\cr}$$ Each $J_i$ can be written as a sum of two diagonlizable matrices, $J_i=R_i+S_i$, $$R_i=\pmatrix{1&1&0&\dots&0\cr0&2&1&\dots&0\cr\vdots&{}&\ddots&\ddots&\vdots\cr\vdots&{}&{}&m-1&1\cr0&\dots&\dots&0&m\cr}$$ and $$S_i=\pmatrix{a_i-1&0&0&\dots&0\cr0&a_i-2&0&\dots&0\cr\vdots&{}&\ddots&\ddots&\vdots\cr\vdots&{}&{}&a_i-(m-1)&0\cr0&\dots&\dots&0&a_i-m\cr}$$ $R_i$ is diagonalizable since it has distinct eigenvalues, and $S_i$ is diagonal. Then $J=R+S$, where $R$ and $S$ are composed of the blocks $R_i$ and $S_i$, respectively, and are diagonalizable, say $R=Q^{-1}FQ$ with $F$ diagonal ($S$ is already diagonal). So $$C=P^{-1}JP=P^{-1}(R+S)P=P^{-1}RP+P^{-1}SP=P^{-1}Q^{-1}FQP+P^{-1}SP=(QP)^{-1}F(QP)+P^{-1}SP$$ is a sum of two diagonal matrices.

So, every matrix is a sum of two diagonalizable matrices, and every diagonalizable matrix is a cube, hence, every matrix is a sum of two cubes, hence, the set of all sums of two cubes, being the same as the set of all matrices, is closed under multiplication.